# use xmlrpc to authenticate and create a node via services module 3.x and drupal 7

Tags: 7, services

I want to use services module 3.x, drupal 7 and xmlrpc to create a node from a php client. However, I don't know how to deal with the authentication. I enable the session authentication but I don't know what I should do and I get error: HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized: Access denied for user anonymous.

ps: I can get session name and session id from user.login

Comment: change permissions for anonymous user and check again

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is valid after SERVICES 3.5 (lower version are deprecated, anyway)

```
// USER LOGIN
$authenticate = xmlrpc($settings['server'], Array('user.login' => array($settings['user'] , $settings['password']),));

// CREATE HEADERS
$options['headers']['Cookie'] = $authenticate['session_name'] . '=' . $authenticate['sessid'];

// GET TOKEN
$token = xmlrpc(url($this->endpoint, array('absolute' => TRUE)), array('user.token' => array()), $this->headers);

//INSERT TOKEN INTO HEADERS
$options['headers']['X-CSRF-Token'] = $token['token'];
```

At this point you should be authenticated and could create nodes at will.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below given link and I am sure it will help

[How do I POST a new node using the Services module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77256/how-do-i-post-a-new-node-using-the-services-module)

Before doing please read https://drupal.org/node/1354202
Services 3 - POST node.create with custom fields ...test your services first on various tools. link browser add-ons and other apps. after that you can use this services in any flatforms like PHP, JAVA ....etc

Answer (score 0):

As you said After logging in using web service ,you are getting a response with session name and session id.For making a request to create a node ,you should specify the session name and session id in the header of the request.
The session name and id are used for authentication,If it does not match with the current session,then you will not be authorized